# How to get error message in html page from server

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring-mvc

I have some problems with error handling in spring mvc web-application. I made a custom html page (note, not jsp) and I'd like to make it something like a universal page that will be able to show error message(thrown by server). I've seen some decisions of this problem with jsp, but I'd like to work with html. Can anybody help me with it? What type of error handling from spring mvc have I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

well, if you you really want to solve it by showing different html pages, then you can customize it using ExceptionHandler annotation on method which return different html page for each exception.

example:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Throwable.class)
public String exceptionHandler(Throwable ex) {
    ...
    return "pathtoYourHtml.html";
}
```

Comment: No, I want to use one html page for all exceptions. And according to the thrown exception, this page will have different content

Comment: so you need to combine it with jsp or some template engine like freemarker or velocity... then you can pass model with your errors as strings

Comment: okey, great thanks. I hoped that it is possible to make it without jsp or template engine=(

Comment: dont worry, freemarker is kinda easy to use and configure